# Java - Can't get getText in jTextArea to work properly

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextarea

I have a seperate JFrame where there is a text box (jTextArea) that takes numbers as inputs, each separated with a new line. Upon closing the JFrame with the text box, the data is supposed to be stored in an ArrayList of integers. The ArrayList is checked when clicking a button in the main JFrame and errors are logged if they happen.

The code for the JFrame with the jTextArea looks like this:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        boolean success = false;
        try{
            selectedTime = Long.parseLong(jTextField1.getText());
            if(selectedTime >= 10000){
                success = true;
                if(!jTextArea1.equals("") && !jTextArea1.equals(null)){
                    try{
                        for(int i = 0; i < jTextArea1.getLineCount(); i++){
                            n = Integer.parseInt(jTextArea1.getText(jTextArea1.getLineStartOffset(i),jTextArea1.getLineEndOffset(i)));
                            if(n <= 172){
                                worldsChosen.add(n);
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        errorsHappened = true;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The specified time was not above or equal to 10000 ms. Please try again.");
                success = false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The specified time was not set in numbers exclusively. Please try again.");
            success = false;
        }
        if(success){
            gui.hideWorlds();
        }
    }
```

Note: it also checks whether a text box has a number input equal to or above 10000 (this works).

The code for the main JFrame:

```
 if(jCheckBox5.isSelected()){
            checkWorld = true;
            if(!worldsChosen.isEmpty()){
                changeWorlds = true;
            }else{
                log("You've selected the option for automatic world switching,");
                log("but all of your inputs weren't formatted correctly.");
                errorsHappened = true;
            }
        }else{
            errorsHappened = false;
        }
if(errorsHappened == true){
                log("One or multiple worlds weren't added due to incorrect formatting.");
                log("Retry to make script automatically change worlds.");               
            }
```

Whenever I run the script with the check box selected and something formatted correctly in the text area 
(like this):

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

etc.

It outputs all of the log messages (as if the check box had been selected but none of the inputs were formatted correctly).

I've tried to the best of my knowledge to fix this, but I just can't see how it messes up.

Any help appreciated :).

Mike Haye.

Comment: "if(!jTextArea1.equals("") && !jTextArea1.equals(null))"
: I suppose it is jTextArea1.getText() you want to test. Btw .equals(null) is an abomination, replace with ==null

Comment: `!jTextArea1.equals("") && !jTextArea1.equals(null)` would always be true (since JTextArea != String and jTextArea1 != null )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [api doc of getText(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28int,%20int%29): the second argument is not an offset. It's a length.

Side note 1: it should probably be easier to get all the text as a single string and split on newline chars, and the parse every string into an integer.

Side note 2: The test `if (jTextArea1.equals(""))` can't succeed. A JTextArea instance will never be equals to a String instance.

Comment: Used the Scanner class and it's methods. Thanks for the tip - it proved much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't check the complete program, but this is wrong:

```
if(!jTextArea1.equals("") && !jTextArea1.equals(null)){
```

Did you forget to add the call of `getText()` ? The line as it is will always be evaluated to `true`, because the instance object of JTextArea is never equal to `""` or `null`. The latter would imply that the `jTextArea1` object was null itself. Which would give you a NPE when you call the `equals` method.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot this lol... Thank you all for your inputs.. late-night coding..

EDIT: It still doesn't work after remembering to call getText() is there something wrong wih            `n = Integer.parseInt(jTextArea1.getText(jTextArea1.getLineStartOffset(i),jTextArea1.getLineEndOffset(i)));
`?

Comment: Yes, there is something wrong. The sscond argument to getText is not right. See my own answer.

Comment: @JB Nizet 
I still don't see why it shouldn't work. I can see that the second argument is a length, but isn't that essentially what getLineEndOffset() gets? I'm quite puzzled about this. Any suggestions?

Comment: The offset of the end of line is an offset from the beginning of the text area, not from the beginning of the line. So if your lin starts at offset 30 and is 5 characters long, getLineEndOffset will return 35. You're thus passing 35 rather than 5 as the length. Why don't you try it by yourself and/or use a debugger to see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

Do you reset the flag before checking the conditions? Consider the following case:

```
   //suppose errorsHappened is true here 
   if(jCheckBox5.isSelected()){ //we get true here
        checkWorld = true;
        if(!worldsChosen.isEmpty()){ //not empty, so this branch is taken
            changeWorlds = true;
        }else{ //worldsChosen is not empty, so this would not be logged
            log("You've selected the option for automatic world switching,");
            log("but all of your inputs weren't formatted correctly.");
            errorsHappened = true;
        }
    }else{ //checkbox is selected, so no reset to false here
        errorsHappened = false;
    }
   //due to the checkbox being selected and worldsChosen not being empty, 
   //errorsHappend is still true (which is wrong)
```